# where clause work only when case is satisfied

Tags: sql

I have made a view that has a `where` clause :

```
WHERE M.Deleted = 0 AND I.Deleted = 0  AND L.Deleted = 0
```

is there a possible way to make `L.Deleted = 0` only work on a specific case? My plan is when the `M.TYPE_ID != 4` then add this `L.Delete = 0` to where clause, and without it otherwise

I tried to make something like:

```
AND CASE WHEN M.TYPE_ID != 4 THEN L.DELETED = 0 ELSE --(i want here to make this entire part of where clause to be invalid if the case is not valid)
```

or there are other ways to do that like intersect the same select above but without that condition ?

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
WHERE M.Deleted = 0 AND I.Deleted = 0  AND
      (M.TYPE_ID = 4 OR L.Deleted = 0)
```

You don't need a `case` expression.

You might find the logic simpler to follow as:

```
WHERE M.Deleted = 0 AND I.Deleted = 0  AND
      ( NOT (M.TYPE_ID <> 4 AND L.Deleted <> 0) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to include the valid condition in two checks and or them together.

e.g.

```
Select * from x where (x.isvalid = 1 and x.deleted = 0) or (x.isvalid <> 1 and x.othercheck = 1)
```